# Get index of click element by class

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="slide">
  <a href="#" class="test">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="other">
  ...
</div>
<div class="slide">
  <a href="#" class="test">Test</a>
</div>
<div class="other">
  ...
</div>
```

Now, when I click on one of the test links, I want to get the index of the parent div. BUT, I want the indexes to be just of the `div.slide` elements.

I've tried the following:

```
$('a.test').click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).parents('.slide').index();
  alert(slideIndex);
});
```

The above alerts 0 for the first link and 2 for the second link. I want it to alert 1 for the second link as it's the second `div.slide`. How can I change what I've done to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass the selector to index(), or use the selector and pass the element -> `$('.slide').index($(this).closest('.slide'))`, either way works :

```
$('a.test').click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).closest('.slide').index('.slide');
  alert(slideIndex);
});
```